# how can we downgrade python version 3.5 to 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, debian

Unfortunately I was upgraded python3 version to 3.5 but I am facing issue with new version now I want to revert the version to 3.4. How can I revert version from 3.5 to 3.4.

Comment: [Have a look at this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924703/how-to-downgrade-to-python-3-4-from-3-5)
Uninstall Python 3.5 by going to control panel, uninstall a program, and then look for Python 3.5, click on it and press uninstall. After that download Python 3.4.

Comment: how can get python graphical access of my debian server

Comment: See my [answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332658/153195) , Replace the first command with the exact python version from here https://www.python.org/ftp/python/